# AJAX call not setting up my destroy method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Was tinkering with my Rails app and sadly broke my delete item functionality. Not sure what made it go astray, but it's no longer getting data about the clicked item at the ajax call to the database.

Getting this error in my console
`DELETE http://localhost:3000/bands/favorite/29 404 (Not Found)`

And this is my Rails server:

```
Started DELETE "/bands/favorite/29" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-21 19:15:19 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/bands/favorite/29"):
```

This is my jQuery delete function with the ajax call:

```
  $('.remove_favorite').click(function(event){

        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $.ajax({
          url: "/bands/favorite/"+id,
          method: "DELETE",
          data: id
        }).done(function(){

        $('.list-item[data-id='+ id +']').fadeOut(1000, function(e){
          $(this).remove();
          }); 
        }) 
      });
```

And have this as my route to the delete method:

```
  get "bands/favorite/:id" => "bands#destroy"
```

My destroy method in the controller:

```
  def destroy
    Band.delete(params[:id])
    render nothing: true, status: 200
  end
```

I wonder if anyone can help me figure out why there is no JSON data being returned at the path: `/bands/favorites/29` and hence failing to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by the server error, the cause of your 404 is your route. Instead of

`get "bands/favorite/:id" => "bands#destroy"`

Try:

`delete "bands/favorite/:id" => "bands#destroy"`

Comment: The get was necessary, but adding the delete route to the file worked.